# How can I create an album through Google Photos API with google-api-python-client?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-python-client, google-developers-console, google-photos-api

I took this [code](https://github.com/ido-ran/google-photos-api-python-quickstart/blob/master/quickstart.py), and it works with one tiny amendment (adding `static_discovery=False`):

```
service = build('photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials = creds, static_discovery=False)
```

But this only reads data.
I want to create an album.
So, I added:

```
response_create_album = service.albums().create(body={'album':{'title':'helloworld'}}).execute()
```

It didn't work having gave me this message:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
```

I used different SCOPES:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly'
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.edit'
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.edit.appcreateddata'
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.appendonly'
```

Nothing worked.

How eventually could I succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the REST API directly rather than one of the REST wrappers:

```
_header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(_credentials.token), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
_google_albums_url = 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums'
_body = {"album": {'title': 'my-album'}}
_response = requests.post(_google_albums_url, headers=_header, data=str(_body))
```

Comment: Why raw REST? Because I found the wrappers a) a bit flaky at times especially with timeouts, b) they changed quite often c) the wrappers didn't always have the functionality I needed so I ended up with a mash up of service wrapper and REST. In the end, I just converted the whole lot to REST calls and my experience is a much more stable app with fewer changes needed. YMMV.